# creating new xml file by C#

Tags: c#, xml

how we can create new xml file by C# in the following situation:

1. its winform.
2. our xml code is in a string str = "<><><><>...etc"

now i want to create an xml file `myxml.xml` which contains everything in str,

please answer in the context and thanks...
need simple source code

Comment: I think he has come string with xml tags and wants to save them to a physical file --> myxml.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[XmlDocument.LoadXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

public class Sample {

  public static void Main() {

    // Create the XmlDocument.
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml("<item><name>wrench</name></item>"); //Your string here

    // Save the document to a file and auto-indent the output.
    XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("data.xml",null);
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    doc.Save(writer);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Hi how about creating a method just for this:

```
private static void CreateXMLFile(string xml, string filePath)
    {
        // Create the XmlDocument.
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xml); //Your string here

        // Save the document to a file and auto-indent the output.
        XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(filePath, null);
        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        doc.Save(writer);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing you want to do is to save the string as a file (and you don't want to do do XML-specific stuff like checking well-formedness or automatic indenting), you can simply use [`File.WriteAllText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx).